# Virtual functions, std::function, and non-copyable objects

Tags: c++, templates, move-semantics, std-function

Below is a simplified, contrived example of what I'm seeing.

#### Problem

I have a virtual function that accepts a `std::function` object.

```cpp
class Foo {
    virtual void bar(std::function<void()> &&f);
};
```

This works fine until I need to capture a non-copyable variable.

```cpp
auto ptr = std::make_unique<int>();

Foo f{};
f.bar([ptr = std::move(ptr)]() {
    // Use ptr...
});
```

#### Question

I understand why this doesn't work: `std::function` doesn't allow non-copyable objects. I also know that, in most cases, the fix would be fo have `bar` accept a template, something like the following:

```cpp
template<typename F>
bar(F &&f);
```

In my specific situation, `bar` must be virtual. Does anyone know of a workaround?

Comment: Doesn't capture by reference work? Is lifetime an issue? I cant imagine how a virtual function would make a difference here.

Comment: Why not make the lambda copyable instead?  `std::shared_ptr` can be constructed from a `std::unique_ptr&&` and would allow the function object to be copyable.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use `shared_ptr` because it can be copied.
2. Use references or raw pointers and manage the lifetime of the functor manually.
3. Create visitor classes and use virtual functions (very old-school).

   ```cpp
   class FooVisitor {
   public:
     virtual ~FooVisitor() = default;
     virtual void Invoke() = 0;
   };

   class FooVisitorImpl : public FooVisitor {
     std::unique_ptr<int> mState;

   public:
     FooVisitorImpl(std::unique_ptr<int> aState)
         : mState(std::move(aState))
     {}

     void Invoke() final {
       // callback code
     }
   };

   // main code
   Foo x;
   FooVisitor v(std::make_unique<int>(0));
   x.bar(v);

   // or, if Foo must retain the callback
   Foo x;
   auto v = std::make_unique<FooVisitor>(/* ... */);
   x.bar(std::move(v));
   ```

Comment: A very nice first answer. I think you can improve on it if you'd care to elaborate on  1 and 2 similar to 3. It seems to me that OP is looking for a quick fix. Welcome to the site!